# How does Postgres refresh materialized views?

Tags: postgresql

...let's say the underlying data of a materialized view is 1 million rows. Then, a single row in that data changes. How does Postgres 9.5 process that? I.e., does it rebuild the materialized view from scratch, or only the parts that are affected by the changed row?

Comment: Like @a_horse_with_no_name says, it materialize everything, but if you need to update just one row, I suggest you read this article: [Materialized views Strategies](https://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/materialized-view-strategies-using-postgresql)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-refreshmaterializedview.html)

> REFRESH MATERIALIZED VIEW **completely** replaces the contents of a materialized view. The old contents are discarded.

<sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

It is essentially the same as:

```
delete from mview;
insert into mview
select ...
```

Where the `select` is the stored query.